# Knockout js passing parameters in click data-bind using knockout secure binding

Tags: knockout.js

I've tried to implement ksb on my knockout js but when passing params in onClick binding will result an error.

I used this line:

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: btnClick.bind($data, '1')">button</button>
```

It will throw an error:

```
Uncaught #<Object> knockout-secure-binding.js: 440
```

How do I pass param on my onClick binding?

Comment: nah ! that should not happen check the sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27764/ . any chance you can reproduce it may be its something to do with `knockout-secure-binding.js` .

Comment: yes, it will not have an issue without knockout secure binding. but sadly I am implementing it for security reason. I want to pass params to optimize the usage of my click binding @supercool

Comment: any chance ? can reproduce your case in fiddle.  i can assist you further as things are smooth in the above fiddle you need to keep something to show your problem . alternatively even you can use `click:function(){btnClick('1')}` .

Comment: @supercool Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27768/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for ksb](https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding) says (note particularly #3, bolding added):

> The language used in KSB in bindings is a superset of JSON but a
>   subset of Javascript. I will call it the sbind language, for
>   convenience.
>
> Sbind language is closer to JSON than Javascript, so it's easier to
>   describe its differences by comparing it to JSON. The sbind language
>   differs from JSON in that:
>
> 1. it understands the `undefined` keyword;
> 2. it looks up variables on `$data` or `$context` or globals (in that order);
> 3. functions can be called (**but do not accept arguments**);
> 4. top-level functions are called with `this` set to an object with the following keys: `$data`, `$context`, globals, `$element`, corresponding
>      to the state for the respective element bound.

To get around this limitation, you can use a custom binding handler that wraps other custom binding handlers, and gives them a bound function.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.curry = {
    unwrap: function (valueAccessor, data) {
        var val = valueAccessor(),
            theFunction = data[val[1].token];
        return {
            bh: ko.bindingHandlers[val[0]],
            fnVa: function () {
                return theFunction.apply.bind(theFunction, theFunction, val.slice(2));
            }
        };
    },
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        var spec = ko.bindingHandlers.curry.unwrap(valueAccessor, data),
            init = spec.bh.init;
        if (init) {
            init(element, spec.fnVa, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        var spec = ko.bindingHandlers.curry.unwrap(valueAccessor, data),
            update = spec.bh.update;
        if (update) {
            update(element, spec.fnVa, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
        }
    }
};
```

Use it like so:

```
<button type="button" data-bind="curry:['click', btnClick, '1', '2']">short</button>
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1o6d2wt/3/).

Comment: spot on . reference discussion here https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-secure-binding/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get create a button which called a function passing in the current context data object as a parameter using the click binding as follows:

```
<div class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: function() {$root.functionName($data)}">
    <!-- content -->
</div >
```

and with a property:

```
<div class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: function() { $root.functionName($data.property)}">
    <!-- content -->
</div >
```